# Every $T_1$, $C_2$, regular space is normal

Tags: general-topology

By my attempt, I know that if $X$ is $T_1$, $C_2$, and regular, then it is metrizable. So is every metrizable space also normal? this seems correct but not sure how to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is every metrizable space normal? Yes.

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $P$, $Q$ be two nonempty disjoint closed subsets of $X$.
First note that if $Y$ is a closed subset of $X$, then for $x \in X$, $d(x,Y)=0$ if and only if $x \in Y$.

For each $p \in P$, set $B_p$ denote the open ball centered at $p$ with radius $\frac{d(p,Q)}{2}\neq 0$ by the above result.

Similarly, for each $q \in Q$, define $B_q$ to be the open ball centered at $q$ with radius $\frac{d(q,P)}{2}\neq 0$.

Now prove that the sets $U=\bigcup_{p\in P}B_p$ and $V=\bigcup_{q\in Q}B_q$ are the required open neighborhoods of the closed sets $P$ and $Q$ respectively.